# How to create enum that contains a Function field with a generic argument and specify that generic in the enum constructor

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an enum in Java that has a Function field that will have a typed generic parameter, and I'm struggling with the proper syntax to get it done. I'm trying to end with something like this:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo<T> {
  private T field;
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum Bar {
  A((baz) -> {
    return SomeClass.someFunctionThatOnlyAcceptsStrings(baz.getField());
  }),
  B((baz) -> {
    return SomeOtherClass.someFuntionThatOnlyAcceptsIntegers(baz.getField());
  });
  
  private Function<Foo<?>, String> func;
}

public class CoolGenerator {
  public static <T> String createCoolToken(T payload, Bar payloadType) {
    Foo<T> opts = new Foo<T>(payload);
    return payloadType.getFunc().apply(opts);
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strToken = createCoolToken("someStr", Bar.A);
    String intToken = createCoolToken(13, Bar.B);
    
    System.out.println("strToken is " + strToken);
    System.out.println("intToken is " + intToken);
  }
}
```

Here are the things I've tried:

1. This will sort of work, except it's ugly and causes me to have to handle runtime null checks and such. Not ideal:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo<T> {
  private T field;
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum Bar {
  A((baz) -> {
    if (baz.getField() instanceof String) {
      return SomeClass.someFunctionThatOnlyAcceptsStrings(baz.getField());
    }
    return null;
  }),
  B((baz) -> {
    if (baz.getField() instanceof Integer) {
      return SomeOtherClass.someFuntionThatOnlyAcceptsIntegers(baz.getField());
    }
    return null;
  });
  
  private Function<Foo<?>, String> func;
}
```

2. This gives the error "Lambda expression's parameter baz is expected to be of type Foo<? extends Object>", and I don't understand why (I also tried without the "extends Object" in the generic):

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo<T> {
  private T field;
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum Bar {
  A((Foo<String> baz) -> {
    return SomeClass.someFunctionThatOnlyAcceptsStrings(baz.getField());
  }),
  B((Foo<Integer> baz) -> {
    return SomeOtherClass.someFuntionThatOnlyAcceptsIntegers(baz.getField());
  });

  private Function<Foo<?>, String> func;
}
```

3. Trying to explicitly create these constructors gives an Erasure error (this one is obviously wrong, but I included it anyway):

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo<T> {
  private T field;
}

@Getter
public enum Bar {
  A((Foo<String> baz) -> {
    return SomeClass.someFunctionThatOnlyAcceptsStrings(baz.getField());
  }),
  B((Foo<Integer> baz) -> {
    return SomeOtherClass.someFuntionThatOnlyAcceptsIntegers(baz.getField());
  });

  private Function<Foo<? extends Object>, String> func;

  private Bar(Function<Foo<String>, String> func) {
    this.func = func;
  }
  
  private Bar(Function<Foo<Integer>, String> func) {
    this.func = func;
  }
}
```

I feel like I'm one step away from understanding, but I'm not sure if this is even possible, or what else to try. I'd like to avoid switching to a class, if possible. I'm hoping for suggestions or enlightenment.

Edit: Updated code example above to better illustrate why I'm trying to do this. I want to be able to easily extend Bar in the future to accept more potential option types that will be handled in their unique way but always return a string.

Edit 2: Removing images and replacing with code snippets

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible with enums; each enum value has to be assignable to the same one enum type, which runs counter to what you're trying to achieve. It's honestly been a minute since I've used Java ( :'( ), but I think sealed classes are what you're looking for.

Comment: Option 1 does indeed work, but comes with the null check requirement, and won't quite enforce the types. I'd also be okay with some version where I take in a class parameter in the enum and it's used to enforce the type. Just not sure how I'd do that either.

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe the specific application scenario? Why is it necessary to use a Function type approach? Is it possible to simply write a method and then implement it within each enumeration like this:

```
class Foo<T> {
    private T field;

    public Foo(T field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public T getField() {
        return field;
    }
};

public enum Bar {
    A("aaa") {
        @Override
        public void someFunc(Foo<?> foo) {
            System.out.println("I am " + this.getCode());
            System.out.println("Hello: " + foo.getField().getClass());
        }
    },
    B("bbb") {
        @Override
        public void someFunc(Foo<?> foo) {
            System.out.println("I am " + this.getCode());
            System.out.println("I'd like to do some different: " + foo.getField().getClass());
        }
    },
    ;

    private String code;

    Bar(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void someFunc(Foo<? extends Object> foo) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar.A.someFunc(new Foo<String>("String Value"));
        Bar.B.someFunc(new Foo<Integer>(6666));
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this solution would solve the problem you're encountering.

Comment: The idea here is to have a registry of various types of tokens that can be generated with different properties based on the enum type. So Bar.A.getFunc().apply(opts) would always require that the opts object contains a string payload, whereas Bar.B.getFunc().apply(opts) would always require an integer payload. I'd like it to be an enum so that I can avoid using a giant switch statement that needs to be maintained/updated, I simply need to add another enum with the generator function and then pass the new enum type and it would all work and be type-safe. I'll update the question to show that.